# JavaFX EqualizerBand without playing audio

Tags: media-player, javafx-2

i would like to know if it is possible to use and display the equalizer band, without actually playing audio.  I have information about level of noise corresponding to choosen band range.  I would like to display that information in the form of audio equalizer band.  Thank you.

Comment: If you have numbers at any given point in time (noise), you can display them in any form: set of Rectangles, or text, or BarChart. What is your question? :)

Comment: I was wondering if the AudioEqualizer could work without media source and MediaPlayer, instead of having to draw rectangles myself to have an Equalizer band.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioEqualizer.html ? This class doesn't draw anything, just provides data. FX as library doesn't have equalizer control just an ability to build one.

But there is a lot of equalizers build on top of JavaFX capabilities. E.g.

- http://fxexperience.com/2012/01/fun-javafx-2-0-audio-player/
- AudioChart in Ensemble sample: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html

You can take any of that samples and substitute MediaPlayer bands output with your own data.

E.g. download project from fxexperience.com. Open it and find FxExperiencePlayer file. There is next line there:

```
    spectrumListener = new AudioSpectrumListener() {
    ...
```

Here is listener created which updates UI according to bands. Instead of providing that listener to MediaPlayer call it yourself. E.g.

```
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                final float[] magnitudes = new float[10];
                for (int j = 0; j < magnitudes.length; j++) {
                    magnitudes[j] = random.nextFloat() * -100f;
                }

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        spectrumListener.spectrumDataUpdate(0, 0, magnitudes, null);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

and comment next line to disable media player:

```
    //mediaPlayer.setAudioSpectrumListener(spectrumListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and great samples.  But I don't see how can i substitute MediaPlayer bands output with my own data, unless I have a look at the source code of MediaPlayer.  Don't know if it is possible to have it though.

Comment: Great stuff, didn't know we could call it just like this.  Thanks for your valuable help.